# Removing the Bracket from the First Line of bmatrix

Tags: matrices

How can I write a matrix with a header line that is not bracketed? I have used the following code to produce the results below. In addition of being ugly, it is impractical when I need to align the first row, n1, ..., n6 with the matrix columns.

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

  \begin{document}
   \[ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n_1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n_2\ \ \ \ n_3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n_4\ \ \ \ n_5\ \ \ \ n_6\]
    \[ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0.960 & -0.977 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.983\\
        0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0.977 & 0 & -0.983 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       \end{bmatrix}
       \begin{bmatrix}n_1\\n_2\\n_3\\n_4\\n_5\\n_6\end{bmatrix} =
       \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 100\end{bmatrix} \]
 \end{document}
```

[image: desired output, notice that the first line is not well aligned with the matrix]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution based on `blkarray`: I define a `bheadmatrix` environment (oxymoron intended). It accepts two optional arguments thanks to the `xparse` package: the row with the column heads (no default), and the specifiers of the `blockarray` environment. The latter defaults to (up to) 10 centred columns.
I had to add a strut at the beginning of the first bracketed row and a negative strut at the end of the last one, because for some reason, the default default construction of brackets provided by the `blockarray` package are too short.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{xparse} 

\newcommand\topstrut[1][1.2ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}
\newcommand\botstrut[1][0.9ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[b]}}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{bheadmatrix}{O{}O{*{10}{c}}}{%
\begin{blockarray}{#2}
#1 \\[-0.8ex]
\begin{block}{[#2]}
\topstrut}%
{%
\botstrut\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
}%

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bheadmatrix}[n_1 & n_2 &n_3 &n_4 &n_5 &n_6][*{6}{r}]
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0.960 & -0.977 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.983\\
    0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0.977 & 0 & -0.983 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bheadmatrix}%
\begin{bheadmatrix}n_1\\n_2\\n_3\\n_4\\n_5\\n_6\end{bheadmatrix}
= \begin{bheadmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 100\end{bheadmatrix}
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`kbordermatrix`](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

    \[ \kbordermatrix{
       & n_1   & n_2    & n_3 & n_4    & n_5 & n_6   \\
       & 1     & -1     & 0   & 0      & 0   & 1     \\
       & 0.960 & -0.977 & 0   & 0      & 0   & 0.983 \\
       & 0     & 1      & -1  & -1     & 0   & 0     \\
       & 0     & 0.977  & 0   & -0.983 & 0   & 0     \\
       & 0     & 0      & 0   & 1      & -1  & -1    \\
       & 0     & 0      & 0   & 0      & 0   & 1     \\}
       \begin{bmatrix}n_1\\n_2\\n_3\\n_4\\n_5\\n_6\end{bmatrix} =
       \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 100\end{bmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And that is not on CTAN because???

Comment: According to the author (Kim C. Border): "I have not put them on the CTAN because I do not want the responsibility of supporting them properly. But do feel free to help yourself to any of them. I offer no warranty. The usual rules apply: You may freely copy and use these files. You may give them away free to anyone. You may freely modify them, as long as you change the name of the files."

Comment: It is jut because many users does not know how to install packages manually, so IMO it is best to recommend packages that are on CTAN. He could just release it as unmaintained and let others take over maintenance if they wanted to.